# XCode stops when connect to BLE device

Tags: xcode

I am new to iOS development, and study about Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0) for iOS.

When I click the `BLE device` on the `tableView` which I have scan.

If I didn't use `XCode` to run the project on `iPhone 5C` , it can connect to the `BLE device` and change to the other `ViewController`.

But it stop like the following picture when I run the project on the iPhone by `XCode`.

[image]

Could someone teach me why this happened ?

And how to debug with this condition ?

I am new for IOS , so...sorry about my question if there has any stupid.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the picture shown above there is a break point, hence xcode stops executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put a BreakPoint. Click on the "blue arrow" (near the green light).

Answer (score 0):

You use debugger this blue arrow near green small arrow.. it is used for step by step checking that whereas our app work Fine..
   Just Remove it and run again Your problem will Solve...
   Just Hold it And throw in coding area  or just click on that..